# Update gradle android studio

Tags: android, flutter

```
flutter_barcode_scanner\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\values-w???dp-v13: Error: Invalid resource directory name

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This message has been shown after I try to run my app in Android studio. how can I figure out where is the problem and resolve it.

Comment: Either upgrade or downgrade the flutter_barcode_scanner dependency.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to `flutter clean -> Invalidate Cache and Restart` on android studio -> `flutter pub get` and also make sure you extend FlutterActivty:

Java:
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {}

Or for Kotlin:
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {}

For more info see [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration).